# Looping through another array for conditions using forEach loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I've created a function called checkLength(input, min, max) which takes in a username and password input as shown below.

```
checkLength(username, 3, 15);
checkLength(password, 8, 25);
```

However, I'm looking to pass in an inputArray, minArray, maxArray to reduce the repetitiveness  using a forEach loop. But it seems like a forEach loop can only take in one array at a time. Any suggestions on how I can improve this?

```
checkLength2([username,password], [3,8], [8,15])

function checkLength2 (inputArray, minArray, maxArray, i=0) {
inputArray.forEach(input => {
    if (input.value < minArray[i]) {
        //another error function
        i++;
    }
});}
```

Comment: I think you original approach with two function calls makes a lot more sense

Comment: `[[username, 3, 8], [password, 8, 15]].forEach(args => checkLength(...args));` is an approach.

Comment: `I'm looking to pass in an inputArray, minArray, maxArray` and now you have 3 lists that you need to maintain and keep in sync

Answer (score 1):

You should try index from `forEach` loop.

```js
function checkLength2 (inputArray, minArray, maxArray) {
  inputArray.forEach((input, i) => {
      if (input.value < minArray[i]) {
          // do something
      } else if (input.value > maxArray[i]) {
          // do something else
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show the same message you can try this out. or else you can use if/else statement for checking both the minArray and maxArray

```
function checkLength2(inputArray, minArray, maxArray, i = 0) {    
  for (let index = 0; index <= inputArray.length; index++) {    
    if (inputArray[index].value < minArray[index] && inputArray[index].value>maxArray[index]) {    
      //error
    }
  }
}
```